# rasterVis map plotting bathymetry and terrain

Tags: r, raster

I have a raster of an archipelago (Fiji) featuring bathymetry (i.e. negative) values for oceanic expanses and altitude data for the island landmass (i.e. positive values) - see attached. I am using rasterVis package in R and want to color the map so the bathymetric data is shades of blue and the landmass is shades of green. I'm using brewer.pal to generate blue and green palettes then combine them as a themes then use "levelplot" function with the 'at = ' option to determine where the crossover from blue to green is (with numbered sequences from the lowest bathymetric point - -5150m' - to the highest mountain - 1200m. Despite altering the seq length [image: rasterVis rendering of Fiji]values (many times) within 'at = ' I cannot get the crossover to centre on zero (i.e. transition from ocean to land - the legend at the image shows that zero is blue and therefore the island landmasses are too small). Here is my code and attached is the best plot I can get. Also, if anyone knows how to overlay an outline map of Fiji on top that would also be great (seems I cannot use 'map' function with this).

```
fj<-raster('FJ.asc')
greens<-brewer.pal(9,"Greens")[c(5,6,7,8,9)]
blues<-rev(brewer.pal(9,"Blues")[c(4,5,6,7,8,9)])
myTheme<- rasterTheme(region = c(blues, greens))
col_breaks = c(seq(-5150,-0.0001,length=50), seq(0.0001,1200,length=50)) 
levelplot(fj, par.settings = myTheme, at=col_breaks)
```

Sorry I cannot attach my ascii raster

Many thanks

Clive

Comment: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/johnbaums/306e4b7e69c87b1826db) might be useful. (See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750235/plotting-a-raster-with-the-color-ramp-diverging-around-zero/33767545#33767545).)

Comment: Ah very cool thanks

Comment: You may want to use `rasterVis::gplot` to do it in {ggplot2} with which you can use `scale_fill_gradient2`, which is build to have a fixed `midpoint`. Then, if you want to add the marginals on your plot, have a look about {ggExtra} answer of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545035/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 2):

Add a contour plot (I have not a Fiji DEM and I used less breaks):

```
levelplot(fj, par.settings = myTheme, at=col_breaks) + contourplot(fj, at = 0.0001 , labels = F)
```

[image]

---

Add more breaks around 0:

```
levelplot(fj, par.settings = myTheme, at=col_breaks) + contourplot(fj, at = c(-0.00001,0,0.0001) , labels = F)
```

[image]

---

Use a vector file with land borders (you can obtain it on [Diva-GIS layers](http://www.diva-gis.org/Data):

```
shp <- raster::shapefile('path/to/shapefile.shp')

if (proj4string(fj) != proj4string(shp)) {
  shp <- spTransform(shp, proj4string(fj))
}

levelplot(fj, par.settings = myTheme, at=col_breaks) + layer(sp.polygons(shp))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much that helped a lot but it seems the crossover point is still actually wrong and seems like a lot of hit and miss to get it accurate at zero without knowing what is specifically required to do it with precision. C